# Set RestSharp Content-Type application/atom+xml;type=entry

Tags: c#, http-headers, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp 107.1.3 and I'm struggling to correctly set the request headers. It worked in RestSharp 106.6.9, but since upgrading, the request fails with the message:

`StatusCode: NotAcceptable, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: 1346)`

and the content-type is always "text/html" which is wrong.

[image]

The returned HTML says `406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page`

This is the code that worked with the old version of RestSharp but it isn't working in the new version:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient( appSettings.BaseURL )
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator( appSettings.User, appSettings.Password )
};

RestRequest request = new RestRequest( "GL_GeneralJournalHeaderSPECIAL", Method.POST );
request.AddHeader( "Accept", "application/atom+xml;type=feed" );
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter( "application/atom+xml;type=entry", sdata, ParameterType.RequestBody );
request.AddXmlBody( sdata );
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;

IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync( request );
```

This is what I'm attempting to use with the new version of RestSharp. The commented lines, in every possible combination, are my attempts to get it to work.

```
var options = new RestClientOptions()
{
    BaseUrl = new Uri( appSettings.SaBaseUrl ),
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = ( sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors ) => true

};
var client = new RestClient( options )
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator( appSettings.UserName, appSettings.Password ),
};
//client.AddDefaultHeader( KnownHeaders.Accept, "application/atom+xml;type=entry" );

var request = new RestRequest( "GL_GeneralJournalHeaderSPECIAL", Method.Post )
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml
};
// request.AddHeader( "Accept", "application/atom+xml;type=entry" );
//request.AddHeader( "Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry" );
// request.AddBody( transaction.SData );
//request.AddXmlBody( transaction.SData );
request.AddParameter( "application/atom+xml;type=entry", transaction.SData, ParameterType.RequestBody );

var response = await client.ExecuteAsync( request );
```

What am I doing wrong? I have read over [the documentation](https://restsharp.dev/v107/) several times, but I must still be missing something!

Comment: What's `transaction.SData`? Type, content?

Comment: It's an XML (SData https://sage.github.io/SData-2.0/pages/core/0302/) string.

Comment: `AddXmlBody` adds an object, it doesn't suppose to be used with pre-serialized payload. If you want to send a pre-serialized string, use `AddStringBody(serializedString, contentType)`

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyZimarev! I overlooked AddStringBody and that's what I needed. I used `request.AddStringBody( transaction.SData, DataFormat.None );` with `request.AddHeader( "Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry" );` which set the correct headers. If you change your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddXmlBody` method adds an object, which RestSharp will serialize to XML and send the serialized body. It doesn't suppose to be used with a pre-serialized payload.

If you want to send a pre-serialized string, you need to use `AddStringBody(serializedString, contentType)`.

The `AddStringBody` is just a wrapper of adding a new `BodyParameter` instance:

```
public static RestRequest AddStringBody(this RestRequest request, string body, string contentType)
    => request.AddParameter(new BodyParameter("", body, Ensure.NotEmpty(contentType, nameof(contentType))));
```

You can use `request.AddParameter(new BodyParameter(...))` if you need the body parameter to have a specific name.